# How to stop an Android emulator from Eclipse or Emulator button?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just wonder how do I stop or exit Android emulator if I want to modify the source code and run again?

Do I just click on the emulator the "Power" button?

Comment: just re-run the app from eclipse, you don't need to stop the old one, the emulator will stop itself

Comment: it actually repacks your apk and rerun it in the emulator again

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the emulator is the equivalent of rebooting a phone everytime you test something.

It takes a lot of time and it's completely unnecessary (unless you're testing something that happens during reboot). Just re-run the code, Eclipse and adb will do the rest. Keep the window of the emulator open all the time, it will just re-install the apk onto it.